# Dynamic timezone change for OpenWrt (Chaos Calmer), NTP

Tags: scripting, ntp, timezone, openwrt

I have this idea for my routers running OpenWrt, since for them there is no way of knowing in what time zone they are by default. What if there was a list of lets say three time servers each per one area (Europe/Rome, Asia/Seoul etc) already inside and there would be a script to check which time server is currently closest (pinging etc), and according to that it would select the proper time server from the list and set the right timezone settings inside etc/config/system.

I'd like to have that function, but I don't quite know how to implement it. Or is there an already working way for OpenWrt routers to detect what timezone they're in that I am not aware of?

So far I've always been changing time settings by hand, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: How about just running them with UTC and don't care about time zones? If you have to correlate logs with different TZ settings, it just is a nightmare anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Servers should use UTC in order to simplify server management; especially when you are managing resources across multiple time zones. Furthermore ntp knows nothing about time zones, ntp strictly deals in UTC.